# force order of messages with HornetQ

Tags: java, jms, hornetq

I've setup a jms server with HornetQ as a JMS provider (Queue).

I have an application which acts as a producer and another one (different computer) as a consumer.

I understand that the JMS specification doesn't guarantee the order of delivery, but I'm looking for a way to do just that: receive the messages **exactly** in the order they have been sent, even if it's provider specific.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently this can be achieved by disabling the consumer cache. This is done by changing the `hornetq-jms.xml`:

```
   <connection-factory name="ConnectionFactory">
      <connectors>
         <connector-ref connector-name="netty-connector"/>
      </connectors>
      <entries>
         <entry name="ConnectionFactory"/>
      </entries>

      <consumer-window-size>0</consumer-window-size> <!-- add this line -->
   </connection-factory>
```

Comment: But by setting the window-size to 0 you have effectively killed a layer of caching which has and will affect performance.

Comment: In my case the order of messages is far more important than some potential performance loss. However if you have a better idea I'd really like to hear it. Thanks.

Comment: Setting this option did not worked for me, tested locally with HornetQ 2.2.5. One Client produces message, one consumes, order is not sequential.

Answer (score 1):

Actually section 4.4.10.2 (Order of Message Sends) of the JMS specification is pretty clear about ordering.

If you have a single producer, and single consumer to a queue or topic subscription, message ordering is always guaranteed even in the presence of redeliveries.

If you have multiple consumers, the client buffering may be redelivered in case of rollbacks or closing your consumer, and the client buffer may be delivered out of ordering.

On HornetQ you also have the message group which entitles extra ordering constraints to the produced messages.